# Iterate only one dict list from multi list dict

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I have a dict of lists like so:

```
edu_options = { 'Completed Graduate School' : ['medical','litigation','specialist'...],

            'Completed College' : ['linguistic','lpn','liberal','chicano'... ],

          'Attended College' : ['general','inprogress','courseworktowards','continu'...],
```

My original code without an attempt at hierarchical matching:

```
for edu_level in edu_options: 
       for option in edu_options[edu_level]

                 if option in cleaned_string:
                        user =  edu_level
                        return user
                  else: continue
```

I'm comparing a string to these lists and returning the key. I want to do it in a hierarchical way.

```
 for edu_level in edu_options: 
        for option in edu_options[edu_level]:

            if cleaned_string in edu_options["Completed Graduate School"]: 
                  user = "Completed Graduate School"
                  return user                              

            elif cleaned_string in edu_options["Completed College"]:
                  user = "Completed College"
                  return user 

             elif option in cleaned_string:
                  user =  edu_level
                  return user
```

These if statements work for the majority of comparison str but don't pick up a few cases. For the first and second if statement, I only want to compare it to the respective list such as "Completed Graduate School". Is there a way to iterate through only that list without using another for loop? Something like

```
Ex: string = Bachelor of Arts: Communication and Civil Service
    cleaned_string = bachelorofartscommunicationandcivilservice
    option = iterating through each item(str) of lists in edu_option
```

I want the graduate and college lists to be run through first because they are smaller and more specific. The error I'm trying to correct is another larger list in edu_options contains sub str that matches to cleaned_string incorrectly.

Comment: Is the cleaned_string a list? or are you looking up for sub strings in cleanded_string?

Comment: cleaned_string is just a str that i want to compare to the strs in the list of edu_options

Comment: So, when you say "elif option in cleaned_string", the option which is a string will be looked up inside cleaned_string (which is also a string). Is this what you intend to do?

Comment: an example: elif bachelor(option) in bachelorofscience(cleaned_string): user = edu_level (from whichever list option came from)

Comment: I don't understand this code at all. The `if` and first `elif` don't examine any of the loop variables, so you could put them before the loop and get the same result. And they don't seem to do anything notably different than the last `elif`, so it seems to me like they could simply be removed. (The only real difference is that they do exact matches instead of substring matches. Since the looser substring matches happen later in the loop, you'd *still* get the same results.)

Comment: Yeah, as @Blckknght suggests, you are not using any variables from the two loops in the first two ifs. But, what I am struggling with is the last elif. Now, you say, elif bachelor(option). Is this in python or pseudo code? What is bachelor in this case? Also, could you give an example of the cleaned_string?

Comment: you're right, my code before this post was a bit different. But my new goal with the first if and elif was to try to get the cleaned_string to match to these lists first since other lists in edu_options incorrectly match based on substring

Comment: I posted an answer; thought it would look messy to write code in a comment. Thought what you want is an equality test than an in test. Don't know whether I really understood the question correctly though.

Comment: I edited hopefully, it made it more clear

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this:

```
for key, val_list in edu_options.items():
    if key == "Completed Graduate School":
        if cleaned_string in val_list:
            #do something
    #Similarly for remaining key types
```

This way, you are restricting the checks specifically to the key types.

Answer (score 0):

```
 for edu_level in edu_options: 
        for option in edu_options[edu_level]:

            if cleaned_string in edu_options["Completed Graduate School"]: 
                  user = "Completed Graduate School"
                  return user                              

            elif cleaned_string in edu_options["Completed College"]:
                  user = "Completed College"
                  return user 

             elif option == cleaned_string:
                  user =  edu_level
                  return user
```